# Microsoft Visual Studio Code doesn't do anything when running an executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I wanted to create a simple local web server using [this library](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib).

So, I created a new project in Visual Studio, created main.cpp and type in this code into my main.cpp.

```
#include "httplib.h"
using namespace httplib;

int main(void) {
  Server svr;

  svr.Get("/hi", [](const Request & /*req*/, Response &res) {
    res.set_content("Hello World!", "text/plain");
  });

  svr.listen("localhost", 8080);
}
```

And I also created httplib.h and copied [this code](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/httplib.h) into my httplib.h.

I ran it. A blank terminal pop-up, then I go to localhost:8080/hi via Google Chrome and it works. There's **"Hello World"** output in there.

Then, I do the same thing with Visual Studio Code. But when I compile it, there's an error says

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUgoSsW.o: in function
> 'std::thread::thread<httplib::ThreadPool::worker, ,
> void>(httplib::ThreadPool::worker&&)':
>
> /usr/include/c++/9/thread:126:
> undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I searched a bit and found a solution. So, I compile it manually using Visual Studio Code terminal by typing "**g++ main.cpp -o demo -pthread**" and it compiled successfully. But, then I try to run the demo via terminal "**./demo**" it just doesn't do anything. I try to connect to localhost:8080/hi via Google Chrome but it said This site can’t be reached.

[image]

**How to reproduce my problem**

1- Create a folder

2- Create a main.cpp in that folder and type in this code into it

```
#include "httplib.h"
using namespace httplib;

int main(void) {
  Server svr;

  svr.Get("/hi", [](const Request & /*req*/, Response &res) {
    res.set_content("Hello World!", "text/plain");
  });

  svr.listen("localhost", 8080);
}
```

3- Create a httplib.h file into the folder and copy [this code](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/httplib.h) into it

4- Compile it via Visual Studio Code terminal by using this command "**g++ main.cpp -o demo -pthread**"

5- Run the build via terminal by using this command "**./demo**"

6- Go to Google Chrome and type this address "**localhost:8080/hi**" If it can't be accessed then that's my problem

*ps: I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04*

Comment: `-pthread` You need to stuff that somewhere in one of them VSC config files, donthathink? Also please do not post shots of text terminals. They are uninformative. If you want to post text, post text. Also please post the code inline, not as links.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without relying on external links